# Can I write a Swift enum case that's only available in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, swift, conditional-compilation

In Swift, I have this enum:

```
enum Foo: UInt8 {
    case bar
    case baz
}
```

I want to give it a failable initializer:

```
extension Foo {
    init?(byName name: String) {
        if name == "bar" {
            self = .bar
        }
        else if name == "baz" {
            self = .baz
        }
        else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, this can't be exposed to Objective-C, so the traditional solution is to use a new case like this:

```
enum Foo: UInt8 {
    case invalid = 0
    case bar
    case baz
}
```

This isn't something I want. I don't want someone to use `.invalid` in Swift when `nil` does just fine. I was hoping I could do something like this:

```
enum Foo: UInt8 {
    #if objc
        case invalid = 0
    #endif
    case bar
    case baz
}
```

But that doesn't seem to do the job. **Is there any way I can write code in Swift that can only be seen and used in Objective-C?** That is, is there any way to write code in Swift that's only ever exposed in the generated `MyModule-Swift.h` file?

Comment: Trivia: for nullable enums, Swift (currently) represents `nil` as the value above the last case (so 2 here). Not sure how you can exploit that for Objective-C interop, especially since you can't export nullable enums to Objective-C.

Comment: Objective C can't represent failable initializers? That seems like it should be possible

Comment: @Alexander The problem here is that `Foo` is represented as a series of `UInt8` constants. `nil` means `0` in Objective-C, so a `nil` `Foo` is just whichever one corresponds to `0`.